# Make different registration form for multi website magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, register

I have multi website magento store and on one website I have to show the default registration form but on the other website I want to show different registration form on other website with many custom fields like the one shown in image below.

[image]

followed steps like in the answer but had no luck.
[Different registration forms on different websites](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/different-registration-forms-on-different-websites/8987#8987)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different registration forms on different websites](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/different-registration-forms-on-different-websites)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I already mentioned that link but that solution didn't work ....didn't have enough reputation to comment so thought of asking new question.

Comment: Your previous question is useful. so, I gave you up vote. Now you can able to comment.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara i doubted that it would be you :)  but needed 50 reputation to comment.

Comment: 50 ?? so, how you could you commented on answer?

Comment: check rules to answer no reputation, to comment on your own question /answer - no reputation issues but to comment on somebody else answer  need 50 reputation . now please don't ask me why ......ask the people who made inconvenient rules.

Comment: Bro. just kidding.  can you chesk solution for this plz http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130775/how-to-add-drop-down-for-cities-at-checkout-page

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara added comments check them.....don't know if they'll be helpful or not .  PS: I'm new to the world of magento.

Comment: Okay. i already checked that, but that is not applying in my website. ceck there for my website checkout. i used OPC.

Comment: it's work try this .. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-formbuilder.html

Comment: @lalitmohan i used it made a form and loaded form in a cms page now when i load that cms page in register.phtml then it gives coding of the form its shortcode

Answer (score 1):

You Have two website so follow this steps

1) go to system->config.->design , at your website level

2) create a new theme folder for your website in `app/design/frontend`

3) add exception theme for website and paste only your `register.phtml` file in that file other files will pickup from your regular theme.

For this you can set exeption theme for this website and put your `register.phtml` form on your different theme , this way you can solve this problem

Comment: please explain how to achieve this ......i'm new to the magento

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: hey your answer helped but I have copied all files to new theme  and set package in design as dropshipping (New created).and all options in themes as rwd (used in other website) but its not showing css . and i don't understand how to create a exception theme ?

Comment: for css you have to copy `skin/frontend/` and copy css and js and image folder to your new theme , and for exception theme you can google it this term you will get good articles on this

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have developed the same thing for my client. And its a very lengthy process to **add new attributes**, **display them in frontend and backend**, **save them on registration**, **make them editable on frontend and backend** and **implement validations**. You can achieve it by following 3 steps:

1. Add new attributes which you want to add in your registration forms. For this folow: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/02/customer-registration-fields-magento1-6/

   > While adding attributes, keep in mind where you want to use those attributes. If you want to include it inside customer address, then it will be different attributes and need to be included inside **customer_address** not inside **customer**.
2. Create separate .phtml files for each form. Include fields as required. You can create this files inside different child themes for different stores.

   > After creating different .phtml files for form. You have to overwrite My account edit.phtml files. If you want to include those fields in checkout process then in thosse .phtlm files also.
3. Create CMS pages for each form and select stores in which you want to display specific form.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show this form as separate CMS page then create CMS page from CMS menu > Pages & place the below code in it

```
{{block type="formbuilder/frontend_form" name="frontend_form" form_id="1" template="formbuilder/form.phtml"}}
```

(replace form_id with your form_id, see form_id from Admin panel > Form Builder menu > Manage Forms)

Comment: i used this in cms page and working fine .my basic requiremnet is to call a different registeration page for different website. So what i did is made a form using extension and added it in cms page now im'm calling that cms page in register.phtml and its showing the code you mentioned.

Comment: How to get form content in registration page?

Comment: $page = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('your_page','identifier');
 echo $page->getContent();   
  put this code in your  register.phtml  file

Comment: i used this and it is showing {{block type="formbuilder/frontend_form" name="frontend_form" form_id="1" template="formbuilder/form.phtml"}}  in the page.